# First button of UITableView as Search as well as Add textfield

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

If you see the screenshot below, its a view from iOS Files app which lets you select tags for a file.

I want to make a similar Tableview which lets user either select existing items or add new items. But I also want the add textfield to be a search field. That is, when the user starts typing there, he also gets search results from the existing items.

[image: Tag Example]

The way I am planning to implement this is...

- Two table views.
- One has a static cell to 'Add' and is not vertically scrollable.
- Right underneath is the second table view with existing itmes, which is vertically scrollable.
- when the user taps and starts typing in the textfield, there is a search side by side, in the second table view and the user can select an item from it as well.
- When there are no matching results, an add button is highlighted and the user can add a new entry.

I want to know what is the best way one can implement such behaviour?

Also,
(In terms of UI Design)
Should one make use of the UISearchBar instead of a textfield?
Or, is it better to simply use the UISearchController?

Comment: Don't use two tableviews. You can use UISearchController and when search result is empty show an cell as add this item and reload the table on didSelect

Comment: I want it to look like the tag view shown in screenshot.

Comment: Yes. You can design like this screenshot